# The effect of 2018 tax deductions, Part 2: head of a household

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

In the [previous question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/96951/the-effect-of-2018-standard-tax-deductions), I asked:

> I read about new standard tax deductions at
>
> https://www.hrblock.com/tax-center/irs/tax-reform/new-standard-deduction-eliminated-exemptions/
>
> Suppose I am not married. Suppose my income is 15K. Then does the new tax deduction means that I will be taxed for 15K-12K=3K?

A. Now suppose I live with my mother for more than half of a year and that I pay more than half of the cost of "keeping up a home" for the year.

Then the above document shows that I can claim myself as a "Head of a Household" with 18K standard deductions.

To prove that (1) I live with my mother for more than half of a year and that (2) I pay more than half of the cost of "keeping up a home" for the year, I will follow

https://www.sapling.com/7604212/prove-head-household-irs

B. Then how can I file my taxes? What additional documents do I need?

Comment: Can you claim your mother as a dependent? To be Head of Household you generally must have a dependent.

Comment: She is 80 years old. What other documents do I need?

Comment: It's not about documents. It's about whether she meets the conditions in the law to be your dependent. Mainly, she has to have less than $4050 income and you have to provide at least half her support.